# Как соединить DataGrid с LINQ запросом?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Уважаемые ребята. Вот уже несколько дней пытаюсь сделать клиент для своей БД. Приложение делается на *WPF*. Пытался придерживаться *MVVM*, но сдался. Думаю, опыта пока мало, и надо сделать сначала по старинке, затем попытаться перевести в *MVVM*. `DataGrid` заполняеться SQL-запросом:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid Name="grdEmployee"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=bd;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password");
string CmdString = string.Empty;
CmdString = @"select b.SchoolName [Наименование] from mko_listschoolitem a
              join school b
              on a.SchoolID = b.SchoolID
              where a.ListSchoolID = 1";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, conn);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
sda.Fill(dt);
grdEmployee.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

1. Хотел бы потихоньку перейти на *LINQ*. Как сделать то же самое, но с использованием *LINQ*.
2. Необходимо сделать, чтобы при изменение значений ячеек `DataGrid` изменения происходили динамически в БД - **без** необходимости создания кнопок *Update/Refresh*.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужен `SqlConnection`, а не Entity Framework?

Comment: Да. Конечно. Он у меня есть (cokoContext). Как мне переделать SQL в LINQ?

Comment: @derkode: думаю, надо перестраивать программу. У вас есть объектная модель? Нету. Какими объектами тогда будет оперировать LINQ?

Вот примеры того, как надо: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386940%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Но мне кажется, что лучше потратить время и выучить Entity Framework.

Answer (score 4):

1. Как уже написали в комментарии, если вы хотите перейти на LINQ вам нужна объектная модель, т.е. для каждой таблицы из БД должен быть создан соответствующий класс в коде. Можете посмотреть [вводную статью про LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/the-linq-to-sql-object-model). Или по [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/absolute-beginners-guide-to-entity-framework)
2. Для того чтобы сделать автоматическую запись изменений в БД нужно в обработке события `DataGrid` `RowEditEnding` - сделать сохранение контекста БД вызвав метод `SaveChanges` этого контекста.
   [Пример.](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=563)